# "Incorrect syntax near 'UNSIGNED'"

Tags: mysql

when I run the following query, I get the error "Incorrect syntax near 'UNSIGNED'". Can you please help me figure out what's going on? Thanks!

```
create table  employees (
    id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key ,
    firstname varchar(25) not null,
    lastname varchar(25), not null,
    email varchar(45) not null,
    phone varchar(10) not null);
```

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but you have an extra comma in your `lastname` row.

Comment: Just checked, and the error persists.

Answer (score 4):

The error message suggests to me you are actually running your DDL statement against a SQL Server instance rather than a MySQL one.

If your server *is* SQL Server and you mistakenly thought it was MySQL and wrote your DDL using the MySQL syntax, you need to fix not just the `UNSIGNED` part but also `AUTO_INCREMENT`. In SQL Server's flavour of SQL, called Transact-SQL, that line would look like this:

```
id tinyint NOT NULL IDENTITY primary key,
```

If you did mean to run the statement in MySQL, then just check your connection settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please, note the extra coma here: `lastname varchar(25), not null,` after `varchar(25)`

```
create table  employees (
id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key ,
firstname varchar(25) not null,
lastname varchar(25) not null,
email varchar(45) not null,
phone varchar(10) not null);
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/YMBH1934